# How can the following coupled system of ODE be solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following system is a coupled ODEs that are dependant on each other.

$$  Y''(x)+A_1 (Y(x) - Z(x)) = A_2 Y(x) - H(x -A_3)$$ 
$$  Z''(x)+B_1 (Z(x) - Y(x)) = B_2 Z(x) - H(x -B_3)$$

Where:

H(x) is the Unit Step Function

Answer (score 0):

Let $\begin{cases}
y_1(x) = Y(x)\\
y_2(x) = y_1'(x)\\
z_1(x) = Z(x)\\
z_2(x) = z_1'(x)
\end{cases}$, you may rewrite as,

$\begin{cases}
y_1(x)' = y_2(x)\\
y_2(x)' = (A_2 - A_1)y_1(x) + A_1 z_1(x) - h_1(x)\\
z_1(x)' = z_2(x)\\
z_2(x)' = (B_2-B_1)z_1(x) + B_1 y_1(x)) +  z_1(x) - h_2(x)\\
h_1(x) = H(x - A_3)\\
h_2(x) = H(x - B_3)
\end{cases}$

and

$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_1(x)'\\
y_2(x)'\\
z_1(x)'\\
z_2(x)'\\
h_1(x)\\
h_2(x)
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
(A_2 - A_1)& 0 & A_1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
B_1 & 0 & (B_2-B_1) & 0 & 0 &-1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
Y(x)\\
Y'(x)\\
Z(x)\\
Z'(x)\\
H(x - A_3)\\
H(x - B_3)
\end{array}
\right)
$